# Could a Windwall form a maze?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

> A wall of strong wind rises from the ground at a point you choose
>   within range. You can make the wall up to 50 feet long, 15 feet high,
>   and 1 foot thick. You can shape the wall in any way you choose so long
>   as it makes one continuous path along the ground. The wall lasts for
>   the Duration.  (SRD p. 192)

The person casting *wind wall* is in a high place - a tower of some sorts to be able to see the area all around him. But do those dimensions have to be uniform throughout? Could you have it 15 feet high from the ground in some places, yet with 10 foot holes in it to allow passage of creatures in others?

If you can't have holes (as presented in one answer) could you lower the wall, by making it 5' high instead of 15' high?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, but it must be continous. No holes.

> You can shape the wall in any way you choose so long as it makes one continuous path along the ground.

You cannot take the wall above ground. If the ground goes up or down, so does the wall.

> [...]  path along the ground

You can dictate the actual dimensions. So you could make the wall taller or shorter in some sections, up to the maximum dimensions:

> You can make the wall up to 50 feet long, 15 feet high, and 1 foot thick. You can shape the wall in any way you choose [...]

"shape the wall in any way you choose" - means it does not need to be uniform. But it must touch the ground and cannot have zero height. it can be thicker, thinner, taller or shorter in some areas.

Comment: Could you LOWER the wall then? (I'll edit the question to ask this too)

Comment: 'so long as it makes one continuous path along the ground' so a maze with only one entrance

Comment: @JesseCohoon added to the answer.

Comment: It sounds like you could probably just make the wall one foot in height at sections you'd like people to step over...

Comment: To give others a chance to answer, I'll wait a day, then accept

Comment: @dalem yeah, but you can either combine efforts with another caster or just make a difficult path. I don't know the real intent of the OP.

Comment: @jessecohoon take your time.

Comment: @DaleM if you combine efforts with another caster (or make 2 castings himself) wouldn't the fact they were in the same area of effect (even if they were not touching) simply make the spells overlap?